# remove specified value from array

Tags: javascript, arrays

How can I check whether an array contains a value, and if so, remove it?
PS: For this exercise, I'm not allowed to use anything more than than .pop, .push and .length array functions.
My logic is the following: if the specified value is within the array, reorder the array so that the last element of it will contain this value, then remove it with .pop. But how can I find this value and reorder it without using anything more than those array functions I specified above?

This is what I managed to come up with so far:

```js
let array_1 = [1,2,3];

if (array_1 == 2){
  //reorder somehow
  array_1.pop();     
}
console.log(array_1);
```

Comment: Are you also not allowed to create an additional, temporary array?

Comment: There's a whole bunch of things here. One: using JS conversion is important. Variables and functions use `camelCase`, classes use `CamelCase` (note lower vs. upper initial). Don't put underscores in your variables. Also, don't use `==`, use `===` unless you absolutely know why you're using `==` (they are different operators). Also, if you declare your array as an array of values, then that's what it is, testing whether it's "2" is never going to do anything.

Comment: There are [a lot of great Array functions](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/JavaScript/Reference/Global_Objects/Array) that you can use here, and I would strongly recommend reading a good tutorial on Arrays first, as part of an intro to JS, to get your familiar with the basics here.

Comment: As far as I know, there's no issue with temporary arrays. The limitation is not using specific functions like .includes.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Using this approach, you are not creating a new array but modifying it. It uses `.pop()`.

```
let array_1 = [1, 2, 3];

// Iterate all array
for (let i = 0; i < array_1.length; i++) {
    // While there is a 2 element in the actual index, move all elements (from i index) to the previous index
    while(array_1[i] === 2) {
      for (let j = i; j < array_1.length - 1; j++) {
        array_1[j] = array_1[j + 1];
      }
      // Now remove the last element (since we move all elements to the previous index)
      array_1.pop();
    }
}

console.log(array_1);
```

Here a snippet so you can try it

```js
let array_1 = [1, 2, 3, 4, 2, 5, 2, 6, 2];

for (let i = 0; i < array_1.length; i++) {
    while(array_1[i] === 2) {
      for (let j = i; j < array_1.length - 1; j++) {
        array_1[j] = array_1[j + 1];
      }
      array_1.pop();
    }
}

console.log(array_1);
```

This would mantain the order of the array, but without the "2" elements.

Answer (score 0):

Here's another option using pop

```js
const filter = (array, target) => {
  const newArray = [];

  let tmp;
  while(tmp = array.pop()) {
    if (tmp !== target) {
      newArray.push(tmp)
    }
  }

  console.log(newArray)
  return newArray;
}

filter([1,2,3,4], 2) // [4, 3, 1] Note that it reversed the order of the array!
```

Answer (score -1):

If you are limited to `pop`, `push` and `length`, you can loop over all elements, check if a given element matches the value you are looking for, and add them to a new array using push.

```js
let array_1 = [1,2,3];
let newArray = [];

for (let i = 0; i < array_1.length; i++) {
  if (array_1[i] !== 2) {
    newArray.push(array_1[i]);
  }
}

console.log(newArray);
```

Answer (score -1):

```js
// using splice
// splice(indexStart, how many, replace with)
// example :
let arr = [0,1,2,3,4,5];

// remove at index 1
arr.splice(1,1);
console.log( arr );

// replace at index 1
arr.splice(1,1,"new 1");
console.log( arr );

// merge index 2 and 3
arr.splice(2,2,"merge 2 and 3");
console.log( arr );

// create 2 new items start at index 2
arr.splice(2,2,"new 2", "new 3");
console.log( arr );
```